# How to install different GitHub packages to my website

Tags: github

I want to install a jQuery photo album package from GitHub, but there are so many files, and I do not know which ones to use. It's getting kind of annoying, because I see all these cool packages I want to add to my website, but I am reluctant to download them because I do not know how to install them in my site here is a link to the GitHub package I want to install

https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery

The files that I have for my website are an index.html, CSS stylesheet, a JavaScript file for my scripts, and the jQuery file. How could I add some of the plugins I have to my site?

Comment: Why not use it from a CDN so it's already packaged? It seems like you're in a bit over your head--you night want to take a step back and figure out some basics first.

Comment: because i would rather learn how to install git hub packages instead

Comment: This makes no sense from a practical standpoint. You don't "install github packages", but you may download all the JavaScript files and include them the way you include any other JS files. In this particular case you can use one of the files in the `dist` directory which will include all of the project's JS files, pre-transpiled. You'd have to know what you were using in order to know which CSS files to use, same with images.